# how to extract values from <bound method Server.diagnostics of <Server: ubuntu12_6>>?

Tags: python, openstack-nova, novaclient

I'm using novaclient.v1_1 to get list of instances and trying to extract diagnostics of each server instance.

code i've written

```
instances = nova.servers.list()
  for i in instances:
    val_list = i.diagnostics
    print val_list
```

so here i got output like this

```
<bound method Server.diagnostics of <Server: ubuntu12_6>>
<bound method Server.diagnostics of <Server: ubuntu12_4>>
<bound method Server.diagnostics of <Server: ubuntu12_3>>
<bound method Server.diagnostics of <Server: ubuntu12_1>>
```

so how can i get full diagnostics information of each server instance?? how to extract tap interface info from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output says, `diagnostics` is a *method*. That means you need to call it!

```
instances = nova.servers.list()
  for i in instances:
    val_list = i.diagnostics()     # <---- Add parenthesis here
    print val_list
```