# extract data from <bound method Server.interface_list of <Server: ubuntu12_1>> type of object

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I'm writing python scripts to get information from OpenStack setup. To get the information related to VM interfaces, we need to use "interface-list". My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import novaclient.v1_1.client as nvclient
from credentials import get_nova_creds

creds = get_nova_creds()
#print creds
nova = nvclient.Client(**creds)
instances = nova.servers.list()
val_list = []
for i in instances:
        stat = i.interface_list
        print stat
```

This gives the output as

```
<bound method Server.interface_list of <Server: ubuntu12_6>>
<bound method Server.interface_list of <Server: ubuntu12_5>>
<bound method Server.interface_list of <Server: ubuntu12_4>>
<bound method Server.interface_list of <Server: ubuntu12_3>>
<bound method Server.interface_list of <Server: ubuntu12_1>>
```

How shall I extract the interface data from the above? 
By referring to [how to extract values from <bound method Server.diagnostics of <Server: ubuntu12_6>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441003/how-to-extract-values-from-bound-method-server-diagnostics-of-server-ubuntu12), I added parenthesis to i.interface_list(). It gives AttributeError: name. 
So, how to get the complete information of interface from the above?

Below is the complete trace back of stat = i.interface_list()

```
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mac.py", line 12, in <module>
    print stat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/v1_1/servers.py", line 36, in __repr__
    return "<Server: %s>" % self.name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 458, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(k)
AttributeError: name
```

Comment: please provide full traceback with `stat = i.interface_list()`

Comment: Here is the full trace back of stat = i.interface_list()
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mac.py", line 12, in <module>
    print stat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/v1_1/servers.py", line 36, in __repr__
    return "<Server: %s>" % self.name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 458, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(k)
AttributeError: name